# Adsense overlay ads with amp-auto-ads?

Tags: amp-html

Adsense has those overlay ad types “vignette” and “anchor”. Are those available with [amp-auto-ads](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-auto-ads/)? I can’t find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, auto-ads use overlay depens on his algorithmus.
For vignette you can use [amd-sticky-ad](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-sticky-ad/).

Comment: Do you have code examples which are actually working with AdSense?